# How can I log the outgoing request of urlfetch in google app engine python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, linkedin-api

I'm having trouble getting oauth to work with linkedin in GAE Python and I suspect it's the format of the outgoing request. How can I log or somehow view the outgoing request my devserver is making to the oauth provider?

Comment: have you tried to enable the *--debug* flag in the dev_appserver?

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. But I could use something more. ideally, I'd like to see the full outgoing and incoming requests from the dev server, like you can track in firebug. Is there something I could install on my system (osx) that would do this for me?

Comment: The `--debug` flag seems to have evolved into `--dev_appserver_log_level debug` (whose HTTP verbosity was good enough for me)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by registering an [API call hook](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/11/API-call-hooks-for-fun-and-profit) for URLFetch requests. You can see the complete contents of the request or response object by logging `request.ToASCII()` or `response.ToASCII()`